# Change button background color with my selected color

Tags: c#, css

I am setting the background color of a button from c#,

```
  bt_Save.BackColor=Color.Gray;
  bt_Submit.BackColor = Color.Gray;
```

but i dont want the grey color i want the #c9c9c9 color, i tried  Color.#c9c9c9 it keeps showing error.. how to set the color

Comment: i have found the answer bt_Save.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("BACKGROUND-COLOR", "#FF5050");

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
bt_Save.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#C9C9C9");
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromhtml(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromhtml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Use

```
  bt_Save.BackColor= System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#C9C9C9");
```

*Translates an HTML color representation to a GDI+ Color structure*

**OR**

you can also use

```
bt_Save.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0xC9C9C9);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
System.Drawing.Color myColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0xC9C9C9);
bt_Save.BackColor = myColor;
bt_Submit.BackColor = myColor;
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zys7833%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Check the definition of the `FromArgb`method again. It doesn't support that "type" of input..

Comment: it show error that it has some invalid argument...

Comment: Corrected the answer, it was a type-o (or brainfart) on my part.